# Replace deprecated RaisedButton with ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter, dart, button, deprecation-warning

I used `RaisedButton` this way:

```
RaisedButton(shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
                        onPressed: null,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text("Button", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)))
```

They decided to make `RaisedButton` deprecated and `ElevatedButton` should be used instead. However, `padding` and `shape` properties are missing. How to get the same effect with `ElevatedButton`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `style` property in the `ElevatedButton`, and then you can use `ElevatedButton.styleFrom` and in there you will find the properties like padding and shape.

Here is an example:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.blue,
        elevation: 5,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text(
        "Button",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 5):

Just replace your code with this

```
ElevatedButton(
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
  primary: Colors.blue,
),
onPressed: null,
child: const Text('Button', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code hope its help to you its similar to RaisedButton

```
    ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          fixedSize: Size(90, 15),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(24.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Text("ok"),
      ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Lets try with this and show side by side

```
Column(
              children: [
                RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
                    onPressed: null,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child:
                        Text("Button", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        onPrimary: Colors.blue,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                        )),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                      child:
                          Text("Button", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
```

output:
[image]